# preg_replace in expressionengine control panel

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, expressionengine

I currently have a form developed in my ExpressionEngine control panel posting data to my databse and I am looking to replicate one of the fields, remove all white space and replace with and _. This would work the same way the ExpressionEngine channel entries replicates the Title and converts into the URL Title with _ instead of white space, but i can't seem to figure it out! I have been digging through the docs.

This is what I currently have, please let me know if this is wrong :)

**Replicate Account Name field.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#account_name').keyup(function () {
  $('#account_short_name').val(this.value);
});
});
</script>
```

**The two form fields**

```
<tr>
  <td><?=form_label('Account Name', 'account_name');?></td>
  <td><?=form_input(array('id'=>'account_name','name'=>'account_name'));?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><?=form_label('Account Short Name', 'account_short_name');?></td>
  <td><?=form_input(array('id'=>'account_short_name','name'=>'account_short_name'));?>       </td>
</tr>
```

I have the preg_replace working on standard text, but I am struggling to get it to work on the account_short_name value. Whenever I try to apply it to the input field it doesn't work.

Here is what I have on standard text.

```
<?php 
$str = 'this is an example';
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $str);
echo $str;
?>
```

Many thanks
Ben

Comment: can php get original account_short_name value?

Comment: something like adding the following to the form input array 'value'=>set_value('account_short_name')? The form hasn't been submitted otherwise I could pull the value from the form id

Comment: Please consider reposting at http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com.